# How does this break out of a javascript tag?

Tags: xss

How does putting the alert function `'-alert(1)-'` into a search field, where it ends up inside a script tag actually break out of the script string?

Wouldn't this just be interpreted as an empty string before and after the alert?  And how do the dashes even work to break out?

Comment: Could you show the script that populates the search value into the script/function

Comment: If you construct the full code with the javascript and your injected string, you should be able to see how it all fits together. Just looking at the injected string is not going to work.

Comment: the script string encapsulates it in quotes, so it ends up looking like ''-alert-''     I'm just not sure how this breaks out of the string exactly

Answer (score 4):

This will work if it is injected into a single-quoted string JavaScript context. Example:

```
<script>
var x = '[userinput]';
// do stuff with x
</script>
```

Now, with the injection, the relevant line becomes:

```
var x = ''-alert(1)-'';
```

This executes as `[empty string] [minus] [the result of a call to alert with argument 1] [minus] [empty string]`.

When subtracting from a string, JavaScript will set `x` to [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction), but we don't really care what `x` is, as long as our injected function is executed.

Comment: I already knew how it's interpreted.  So, you're saying the minus signs make javascipt interpret the alert script as not a legal number so it executes?  How do the quotes play a role.  I still don't understand how this works.  thanks